# How to insert a comment in CST (Concrete Syntax Tree)?

Tags: javascript, tree, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm currently working on a project that involves manipulating a Concrete Syntax Tree (CST) in JavaScript. I'm trying to add a comment before a specific token using the following code:

```js
const commentToken = new Token('CommentLine', "this is a comment");
program.insertChildBefore(commentToken, token.parentElement);
```

However, I receive an error message stating `Error: Invalid reference child`. Can anyone help me understand why I'm encountering this error and provide guidance on what should valid ref child when inserting a token in tree & how to correctly insert a comment in the CST before a token?

Referances:

- https://github.com/cst/cst/tree/master
- https://github.com/cst/cst/wiki/How-to-prepend-new-var-statement

Comment: What is `token`? Can you provide the minimal code necessary to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Try comparing the parser output of code with and without a comment, to see what you actually need to insert